# How to remove all characters after a certain character in bash for a whole file

Tags: bash, grep, apt-get

I've found a couple of questions like this, but they don't talk about using a whole file.

I've got a file of packages from my old OS, but I factory reset it and am hoping to make sure that all of these packages are installed.

See the file [here](https://gist.github.com/yamboy1/8e0662ee6dc87b0eb2b88574be52cc6b)

However I don't need all of the extra information after the `/`, I only want the names of the packages, so that I can `sudo apt install`cat packages.formatted`.

How can I remove this using a tool such as `grep`.

#### Example

```
nautilus/oldstable,now 3.14.1-2 armhf [installed]
minecraft-pi/stable,now 0.1.1-4 armhf [installed]
```

becomes

```
nautilus
minecraft-pi
```

NOTE: If you can find a better way for me to install all of these packages, you can answer with that as well,  but that is not the main point of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` for that (or `cut`). Essentially delimiting the file using that character and returning only the first field:

```
awk -F"/" '{print $1}' yourfile > outputfile
```

This can be piped instead, too:

```
awk -F"/" '{print $1}' packages.txt | sudo apt install
```

Assuming `apt` can read from stdin like that.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any good tutorials on `grep`, `awk` or `sed`? I always under estimate the power of these tools

Comment: Also, `apt` and `apt-get` can't be piped

Comment: I think, for learning, your best bet is picking up some regex as all three of these tools become infinitely more useful with regex knowledge (sed is almost entirely built around it). I don't know any good tutorials off the top of my head. Just aim for `awk` if you are dealing with delimited data; `sed` if you need identify chunks of data in a file stream that needs to be changed as it's identified; and `grep` if you need to search out data in a file or file(s). The big trick is knowing which tool to use for whatever task you have.